# An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/error-ex/-/error-ex-1.3.2.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"

Tags: reactjs, npx

When I try to create a new react app with create-react-app, I got the following:

```
» npx create-react-app my-order

Creating a new React app in /Users/ian/myproject/my-order.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.19.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/error-ex/-/error-ex-1.3.2.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/ian/myproject/my-order/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /Users/ian/myproject/my-order has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

And my local environment information is like this:

```
» npx create-react-app --info

Environment Info:

  System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.6
    CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 11.1.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.19.0 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 80.0.3987.100
    Firefox: 72.0.2
    Safari: 12.1.2
  npmPackages:
    react: Not Found
    react-dom: Not Found
    react-scripts: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    create-react-app: 2.1.1
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
yarn install --registry=https://registry.yarnpkg.com/
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is a problem accessing npmjs.com and installing scoped packages. Try to check https://status.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you use NVM (Node Version Manager), you might have this problem occur if you switched away from your primary nodejs version that you first had installed, so just change back if you can:

```
nvm use <original node installation's version>
```

But, if that doesn't work for you and you're feeling desperate, then in your shoes I'd try reinstalling node directly from the website if I can't just use a non-NVM installation: https://nodejs.org/en/

Some people seem to be having an `EACCESS` error, and that might be fixed by changing their registry from http to https.

Example using NPM, rather than Yarn:

```
npm install --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

A similar problem: [Cannot run npm install from nvm, but working well using source from https://nodejs.org/en/download/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66524565/cannot-run-npm-install-from-nvm-but-working-well-using-source-from-https-node)

Comment: this! i had recently cleaned up some globals and reinstalled/centralized my nvm and got hit with this error. since i couldn't switch back to the original node version, i just recloned the repo and all was well. thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your command:

```
yarn cache clean
yarn
```

and it will probably work...

Comment: An unexpected error occurred: "EBUSY: resource busy orlocked, rmdir '/home/sandbox/.cache/yarn'".

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: Doesn't work or answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try with `yarn install --registry=https://registry.yarnpkg.com/`.
Hope it works!